# How to take out 'contact' values from a 'Many2one' field in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

Any Many2one field which is either linked to hr.employee or res.users shows values Home addresses or contacts in the Many2one drop down tool. Anyone has a suggestion on how to stop this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **domain filter** to avoid unwanted results.

For Eg:- In sale order we only see customers although its related object is res.patner, Its because of domain filter( please see the code )

```
                            <field name="partner_id" on_change="onchange_partner_id(partner_id, context)" domain="[('customer','=',True)]" context="{'search_default_customer':1, 'show_address': 1}" options='{"always_reload": True}'/>
```

Here domain filter is " **domain="[('customer','=',True)]"** "

ie. records with only **customer** field is **True** is shown

From your comments:- If you want to see system users only then user **res.users** instead of **res.partner**. Like:-

```
        'user_id' : fields.many2one('res.users', 'User')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Baiju, but what in case of user's ? user_id=True ?

Comment: could you please mention the need of res.users many2one field for better understanding?

Comment: There is a drop down of "Add favourite calendar" in calendar app. When we try to add a user, it shows addresses which are stored in contacts.

Comment: anyone got any idea on this ?

Comment: could you please specify the menu path?

Comment: messaging -> calendar -> then you will get calendar view and then there is many2one field with placeholder text "Add favourite calendar" on the right corner , the field name is "partner_id" and is related with "res.partner"..

Comment: I wanted to get only user names , not the partner addresses or contacts values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92812/discussion-between-baiju-ks-and-shravya-shetty).

Comment: you mean system users (like Administer, Demo user) ??

Comment: yes , it helped, i had to work on javascript file though, not the python